# How to handle: When image is clicked identical image generated using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code below works to make one copy of the image clicked. I am needing the code below to work for multiple images.

For example if I click 5 images on the screen, the same 5 images should generate at the bottom of the page. The user should be able to select 5 out of 10 images. Any thoughts? Thanks!

JS:

```
function changeImage() {
      var imgSrc = 'http://placehold.it/150';

      if (document.getElementById('myImage').src === imgSrc) {
        document.getElementById('new').src = imgSrc;
      }
    }
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" onClick="changeImage()">
  <img id="myImage" src="http://placehold.it/150"></a>
<img id="new" src="http://placehold.it/200">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JQuery `clone()` function

```js
$('img').click(function() {
  $('body').append($(this).clone());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
<img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/000000/ffffff">
<img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/1C90F3/ffffff">
<img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/F2BB7C/ffffff">
```

Comment: You sir are a genius. I had NO idea there was such a simple way to do this. I've had complicated crazy for loops going to try to handle the same logic. Thank you!!!

Comment: @AndrewLeonardi You can also first select multiple images put it in array and then when you click button you append it to body https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/595/

Comment: This is awesome!! Thank you! Any advise on how to display the clicked pictures more properly? Instead of appending them to the body could I put them in a div and style it etc? Thanks for the help!!

Comment: 100% Perfect. I cant thank you enough. This is exactly what I was trying to accomplish and this is an incredibly simple way to do all of it.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: I am glad i could help.

Comment: One question for you. Any idea how I would add a text box next to each image generated for users to write in? (Not worried about backend atm)

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery to do that

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="my-image">
  <img id="myImage" src="http://placehold.it/150"></a>
<img id="new" src="http://placehold.it/200" />
```

**JS**

```
$('#my-image').click(function(){
   //setting attribute src to be equal as src from #myImage
   $('#new').attr('src', $('#myImage').attr('src'));
   //returning false in order to avoid default action
   return false;
});
```

So that is it :)

Just remember to put this code after your html or into

```
$(document).ready(function(){ ..... });
```

I hope this helps.